# different array for different input text

Tags: php, html

hi i want to store value of each input text in different arrays how to do that
for example store value of input text 1 in array 1 and value of input text 2 in array 2 and so  on how to achieve that 
here is the code for print input text

```
for($r=1;$r<=10;$r++)
{
    echo"<form id='ponts'>
    <table>
    <tr>
   <td>Enter point number$r</td><td> <input type='text' id='pt$r' name='pt$r' pattern='[0-9.]+'/></td>

    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>";

}
```

Comment: `name="pt[]"` -> `var_dump($_POST['pt'])`

Comment: `input` value is a string, not an array. If you want to group inputs in arrays, your values should look like `arr1[$r]`, `arr2[$r]` with depending on `$r` value;

Comment: u want one table or many tables ?

Comment: suppose that input text 1 has value =3 so i want to store that value in array1 and that input text 2 has value =20 so i want to store that value in array2 so how to do this automatically that's what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what u are looking for

```
echo"<table id='points'>";
   for($r=1;$r<=10;$r++)
     {
   echo"
 <tr>
 <td>Enter point number".$r."</td><td> <input type='text' id='pt".$r."' name='pt".$r."' pattern='[0-9.]+'/></td>

  </tr>
  ";
}
echo "</table>";
```

i dont know why you are using the form tags here .

Answer (score 2):

I guess I didn't understand well, but the following script may be what you want.

```
<?php

$g=$_GET;

if( isset($g['pt']) ){
  // the form has been submitted.
  $ptValues=$g['pt'];

  print_r($ptValues);

}

echo "<form id='ponts'><table>";

for($r=1;$r<=10;$r++) 
{
       echo "<tr><td> Enter point number$r</td><td> <input type='text' id='pt$r' name='pt[]' pattern='[0-9.]+'/> </td></tr>";
}

echo "</table></form>";

?>
```

Maybe this:

```
<?php

$g=$_GET;

if( isset($g['pt0']) ){
  // the form has been submitted.
  $ptValues=array();

  for($i=0; isset($g['pt'.$i]); $i++ )
    $ptValues[]=$g['pt'.$i];  

  print_r($ptValues);

}

echo "<form id='ponts'><table>'";

for($r=1;$r<=10;$r++) 
{
       echo "<tr><td> Enter point number$r</td><td> <input type='text' id='pt$r' name='pt$r' pattern='[0-9.]+'/> </td></tr>";
}

echo "</table></form>";

?>
```